# How to query XML based on element value

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have an `IEnumerable<XElement>` object that I want to query based on a certain node value, but continually get a `null element` error. How do I select the value of two elements based on the value of a searched element? I am attempting to return `firstName` and `lastName` where `ID == somevalue`.

Here is the structure of my XML:

```
<Profile>
    <ID>123</ID>
    <firstName>Not</firstName>
    <lastName>Registered</lastName>
</Profile>
```

Snippet of my query:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(someXml);
IEnumerable<XElement> nodes = xdoc.Root.Elements();
XNamespace ns = "xmlNamespace";

var name = nodes.Elements(ns + "firstName")
     .Where(x => (int)x.Element(ns + "ID") == 123)
     .SingleOrDefault();
```

I was basing my query on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15199326/select-xelement-where-child-element-has-a-value) article, but I still can't find a mixture that returns what I want.

**UPDATE**

I have tried the suggested answers below and still see no results or receive an `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` exception.

I am still working through the issue and am now trying this:

```
var result = xdoc
    .Descendants(ns + "Profile")
    .Where(x => (int)x.Element(ns + "ID") == 1)
    .Select(x => new { FirstName = (string)x.Element(ns + "firstName"), LastName = (string)x.Element(ns + "lastName") })
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

When stepping through this, the query hangs after running the `Where` clause.

Comment: Why using `XNamespace` here, does the actual XML has namespace?

Comment: Also which line exactly throwing null reference exception?

Comment: Is there only one element in your Xml? If no, then what's the root element, if there's any at all.

Comment: @har07 yes there is a namespace `<source xmlns='http://www.mysource.com/source'>` and then proceeds to have child `<Profile>` nodes.

Comment: @user2596756: Are you aware that you can select an answer for your questions?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose "Profile" is not a root of your XML after all.

So if I am reading your mind correctly you have something like this:

Xml:

```
<root>
<Profile>
    <ID>123</ID>
    <firstName>Not</firstName>
    <lastName>Registered</lastName>
</Profile>
<Profile>
    <ID>124</ID>
    <firstName>A</firstName>
    <lastName>B</lastName>
</Profile>
</root>
```

Code to get profile section where id element equals to 123:

```
var result = XDocument.Parse(yourXml)
        .Root
        .Elements()
        .SingleOrDefault(i => i.Element("ID").Value == "123");
```

Comment: I received an `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` exception when executing line `i.Element("ID").Value == "1"`. Please note that `ID = 1` does exist in my XML schema.

Comment: I posted completely working code. But you have to adjust it for your needs, since you didn't share your xml schema and check the answer from hungndv if your xml has namespace defined.

Answer (score 0):

I do this examples to deal with namespace:

Profiles.xml:

```
<Profiles xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
    <Profile>
        <ID>122</ID>
        <firstName>Not</firstName>
        <lastName>Registered</lastName>
    </Profile>
    <Profile>   
        <ID>123</ID>
        <firstName>Not</firstName>
        <lastName>Registered</lastName>
    </Profile>
</Profiles>
```

Code:

```
XElement xDoc = XElement.Load(@"C:\Profiles.xml");
XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent";

var profile = xDoc.Elements(ns + "Profile")
            .SingleOrDefault(x => x.Element(ns + "ID").Value == "123");
Console.WriteLine("firstName: " + profile.Element(ns + "firstName").Value);
Console.WriteLine("lastName: " + profile.Element(ns + "lastName").Value);
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Your xml Like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Employee>
  <Profile>
    <ID>123</ID>
    <firstName>Kumod</firstName>
    <lastName>Singh</lastName>
  </Profile>
  <Profile>
    <ID>124</ID>
    <firstName>Ravi</firstName>
    <lastName>Ranjam</lastName>
  </Profile>
</Employee>
```

We can access the first Name and Last Name

```
 string strPath1 = Server.MapPath("~/XmlData/abc.xml");
        var ResultOfFirLasName = (from studentProfile in XDocument.Load(strPath1).Descendants("Profile")
                                  where (int)studentProfile.Element("ID") == 123
                                  select new { FirstName = (string)studentProfile.Element("firstName"), LastName = (string)studentProfile.Element("lastName") }).FirstOrDefault();
        string strFirstName = ResultOfFirLasName.FirstName;
        string LastName = ResultOfFirLasName.LastName;
```

You can do with lemda expression too

```
var ResultOfFirLasName1 = XDocument.Load(strPath1).Descendants("Profile").Where(x => (int)x.Element("ID") == 123).Select(x=> new {FirstName =(string)x.Element("firstName"),LastName =(string)x.Element("lastName")}).FirstOrDefault();
```

Same way you again access the first Name and Last Name